# A good windows VNC server to work with OS X Screen Sharing

Tags: macos, vnc, screen-sharing

I have an iMac and a Windows 7 laptop at work now.

I obviously want to work on iMac since it has a bigger screen, but I need to also be able to do stuff (like web site development),that can only be done on Windows machine.

I have installed an Ultra VNC server on Windows 7. I used embedded VNC Viewer (A Screen Sharing viewer) in OS X Lion to connect to my windows machine. The connection is stable, but the screen updates are bad. Screen ofter redraws and I can see it wave-like.

Both machines are in the same LAN, so the connection speed between them should not be a problem. Most likely it is an Ultra VNC performance issue.

What is the best combination of VNC server / OS X VNC Viewer to use? Thank you.

P.S. TeamViewer, for example, provides a much better performance in my setup, but I can't use it on a corporate network for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Microsoft's Remote Desktop for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client). It's free, and the performance is excellent.

The only issue I have with it is that it won't go full-screen on a 27" display, although I think this is a limitation of the graphics card in the PC rather than a problem with the app.

I also had to do manually edit the .rdp file to set the resolution to anything higher than the default max of 1400x1050.

Comment: +1 - You do need to have Windows 7 Pro or better in order to use RDP, but it is your best bet.

Comment: Why so? You can RDP to Windows XP or Windows 2000 machine just fine.

Comment: Windows Vista and later (optionally) configure RDP in a way incompatible with earlier versions.